# Setting folder to have fixed user and group

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, file-permissions

Years ago I signed up for a VPS that had a custom CMS for setting up new virtual hosts. One of the features I really liked was when a new host was created it set up a new folder with a new user for that host. The user and group were locked so even if root made a new file under that folder tree, it would still keep the correct username.

I've tried using ACLs & sticky bit settings to no avail. It's completely possible I'm going it wrong. What's the best way to set this up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This would have been a feature of their software for creating the virtual hosts. It would have used the 'chown' command in the background.

You can set the group ownership with the setgid bit on directories, but a files owner is always the person who creates it. The only way to change the owner is to use the 'chown' command.

You could achieve what this hosting company did by writing a script to perform all the steps required for setting up the virtual hosts in the manner you require.